# JSON Data Masking using PARANOID

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started with Python programming & working on https://pypi.org/project/PARANOID/ to mask the PII details such as `first_name`, `last_name` & `email_address`.

```
{
    "id": 324324,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@abc.com"
}
```

When I am executing `paranoid -i my.json -o output`, all the fields of my json (id, first_name, last_name & email_address) are getting masked. But I don't want to mask id. For that `-l with Xpath to the json` has to be provided.

I have tried various combinations for `Xpath to json`, but still it masks all the fields in the file.

Please guide me.

Comment: What xpath did you try to specify?

Comment: Does `paranoid -i my.json -o output -l first_name, last_name, email` work?

Comment: no, it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library doesn't seems very attractive for me as there's no documentation at all ,the code is very messy and they seem to be overcomplicating some stuff! the only reference to what it can do was [here](https://sonra.io/2019/04/01/paranoid-masking-anonymizing-and-obfuscating-pii-in-xml-and-json-data/) and they just refer to using xpath to process xml not to process json.

I then installed the library locally and verified that xpath doesn't apply to json. But it turns out the library is just a single module( a unique file) with a bunch of functions. So I investigated which functions are being used when you're processing a json file. Only two functions are being used `jsonParse2` and `maskGenerator`. So it was doable to reuse it.

`jsonParse2` Doesn't make sense at all for me as they are parsing a json file manually when there are so many easy tools to use such as the `json` library. I will discard the `jsonParse2` function as it was the main problem to filter which keys should be processed.

I will simply reuse the `maskGenerator` function into my solution then we just pass the keys,values we're interested in to the `maskGenerator`.

CODE Solution
create an input.json file with your json in the same folder as the solution:

```
import paranoid
import json

list_not_to_mask = ["id"]
with open("input.json") as input_file:
    input_dict =json.loads(input_file.read())
    print(input_dict)
    output_dict = input_dict
    for key in input_dict.keys():
        if key in list_not_to_mask:
            pass
        else:
            output_dict[key] = paranoid.maskGenerator(str(input_dict[key]),is_json=True)
print(output_dict)
with open('output.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(output_dict, output_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

OUTPUT
it will also create a output.json

```
the input we have is: {'id': 324324, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'john.smith@abc.com'}
the output we have is: {'id': 324324, 'first_name': 'Vxqt', 'last_name': 'Yiphq', 'email': 'vuxr.kcicc@muj.jbj'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [the-mask](https://pypi.org/project/the-mask/) library. This will make your life easier.

Please check the library's [documentation](https://github.com/parvathirajan/the-mask/blob/main/README.md) for more information.

**How to install it?:**

```bash
pip install the-mask
```

**Usage:**

```py
import json
from mask import mask

data_to_mask = {"first_name": "str", "last_name": "str", "email": "email"}
with open("input.json") as input_file:
    input_dict = json.loads(input_file.read())
    output_dict = mask(input_dict, data_to_mask)

with open('output.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(output_dict, output_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

# Output:
# {
#     "id": 324324,
#     "first_name": "J**n",
#     "last_name": "S***h",
#     "email": "j********h@a**.com"
# }
```